# Android 4.x HTML Scaling down div containing an iFrame causes iFrame content to appear truncated

Tags: javascript, android, css, iframe, webkit-transform

I have a web page with a div that contains an iFrame. I have applied webkit-transform for scaling the div down:. On Desktop browsers as well as on iOS, this works fine, however on Android 4.0.x the content of the iFrame appears truncated. The amount of truncation is proportional to the amount of scaling happening i.e. If I scale the div down to 0.5, only 50% of the scaled down iFrame is visible.

[You can test this link on Android stock browser](http://s1.imfinity.com/demo/test_android/test_fixedlayout.html). The iFrame is covering the correct area but the content visible is even 50% of that. Interestingly, this issue doesn't occur if the scale is above 1.

This behavior replicates without fail on all Android 4.0 devices and on some 4.1 devices as well.

Please suggest any work arounds for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are resize the iframe (container), but if the content (the iframe) does not match the size of the container's.
Scroll will appear to display the content of the iframe.
In the case that the iframe has scroll = "no" its contents will be cut. You should try to put width = "100%" to the elements that are contained within the iframe.
Hope that help you (7 months later).